# SendKeys and Excel works only for 39 rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have some result data in sheet Extract that I need to activate cell by cell and press enter. It's alright for 10 cells but I have over 40 000. 
I'm using small macro in VBA to send F2 and Enter via SendKeys.

I'm running this macro from Sheet called "control" and I don't want to see when script is activate this cells in "Extract" tab. That is why I'm using

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

The code:

```
Sub Refresh()
    Dim sOLD As Worksheet
    Set sOLD = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim lastrow As Long
        Worksheets("Extract").Activate
        lastrow = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To lastrow
            Range("Q" & j).Select
            Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
            Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
            DoEvents
        Next j
        sOLD.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Unfortunately it works only for first 39 rows rest rows in a rage become empty after script. Do u guys know what can cause problem ??

Comment: Why do you need to edit and press enter for each cell? Don't you think there might be a better method that can address an entire range?

Comment: If you are just taking data formatted as text and hitting F2 + ENTER to get Excel to recognize it as #'s, just go to the Data Ribbon -> Text to columns. Done.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong. Can you double check what is the value in lastrow.

Comment: Further to Bacon's comment: SendKeys will send to the active application. Maybe another app is getting activated and intercepting keystrokes. You could try something like: Range("Q" & j).Formula = Range("Q" & j).Text in the FOR loop instead of SendKeys.